# Render image from JSON stored as base64 with other data in React-Native

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

## I have a JSON file that my app retrieves from the api

#### It contains name location and other information along with an image in b ase64 encoding

```
[ { meta: { views: 0, tapped: 0, favs: 0, priority: 0 },
    img: { data: [Binary] },
    special: true,
    _id: 5cace9fbeb520a4d8833bc1b,
    date: 2019-04-09T00:00:00.000Z,
    title: 'Test',
    url: 'http://goole.com',
    body: 'Oh it chaned',
    published: false,
    category: 'Sports',
    location: 'dafasfasf',
    __v: 0,
    publishDate: 2019-04-09T18:30:00.000Z,
    subCategory: 'Footabll' },
  { meta: { views: 0, tapped: 0, favs: 0, priority: 0 },
    img: { data: [Binary] },
    special: true,
    _id: 5cacf8e54b578827e8425c83,
    date: 2019-04-02T00:00:00.000Z,
    title: 'Testasd',
    url: 'http://google.com',
    body: 'wadwadwad',
    published: false,
    category: 'Sports',
    location: 'Random',
    subCategory: 'Footabll',
    __v: 0,
    publishDate: 2019-04-09T18:30:00.000Z },
```

It looks something like this

### I am unable to render the image in react native

I am getting Objects are not valid as a React Child found object with keys{data}
I understand that this is a object thus this error is occurring but i am unable to find a solution for this (its telling me to iterate thought each key while i want to access the specific key).

### this is the function i am calling inside render

```
viewfunc(){



return(
  this.state.dataSource.map((item)=>{

    return(

    < View key={Math.random()} style={styles.slide3}>

      <Text style={styles.text}>{item.title}</Text>
      <Image
      style={{
        width: 51,
        height: 51,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
      }}
      source={{
        uri:
          'data:image/png;base64,${item.img.data}',
      }}
    />
      <Text style={styles.body}>{item.body}</Text>

    </View>)

}
))}
))}
```

I am unable to render this img and also if i try to print the base64 by placing `{item.img.data}` in the text field its returning the Objects are not valid.. error
I am able to access the meta with `{item.meta.views}`
Please i need help!

### edit

This is how i an encoding it when pushing the image to database

```
var newImg = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
var encImg = newImg.toString('base64');
```

### Tried this too

```
  <Image
        style={{
          width: 51,
          height: 51,

        }}
        source={{
          uri:
            `data:image/png;base64,`+item.img.data,
        }}
      />
```

Still not rendering..

Comment: Nothing wrong with code. Try to set base64 static and check.

Comment: i found out the i wasn't using backticks but even after doing that the image is not being rendered. I did put a static uri and that seems to work but i am not getting why its not working with the api image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string interpolation with backticks:

```js
`data:image/png;base64,${item.img.data}`
```

Comment: `source={{ uri: `data:image/png;base64,${item.img.data.data}`,}}` Did this still no image rendered but no error now.I double checked the image is in png format.Any idead? This helped me a lot btw thanks so far i was using inverted commas insted of backticks

Comment: `data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[105,86,66,79,82...]"}` this is inside the data

Answer (score -1):

try something like

```
     <Image source={ uri: `data:${image.mime};base64,` + image.data, width: image.width, height: image.height }
/>
```

Comment: Tried this still nothing is being rendered